# Tastypie not saving uploaded file

Tags: django, tastypie

My application has a tastypie endpoint that received post requests with a file(not big...40-70kb) and is supposed to save the file and then process it. However, it seems the file never gets saved after upload and thus trying to retrieve the file after save fails. I have read in many places about it but it seems tastypie has no one standard way of doing it. Here are my models and resources:

**models**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    track = models.FileField(upload_to='tags/', max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.track.url
```

**api_resource**

```
class TagResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
    track = fields.FileField(attribute="track", null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'tag'
        authorization = Authorization()
        object_class = Tag
        always_return_data = True

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.obj.save()
        #the processing operation on the saved file
        result = recognize(bundle.obj.track)
        bundle.data['tag'] = result
        return bundle
```

When I post a file with Curl:

```
curl -F "track=/path/to/track/track.mp3" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tag/
```

I get an error:

```
SuspiciousFileOperation: Attempted access to '/path/to/track/track.mp3'
```

and upon further investigation, i realized the error is being caused by the intended operation working on the  url of the source file instead of the uploaded file's url.

What i'm I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. Seems like I was not posting correctly using CURL. I now use this to upload the file:

```
curl -F "track=@/path/to/file.mp3" http://1**.**.***.**:8000/api/tag/
```

The '@' before the path was missing before. Adding that fixed it.